# figuring out menu token path for file field

Tags: path-aliases, tokens, navigation, files

I'm trying to use menu token and file (field) path to get a path to display a node's PDF field from a menu link.

I tried with the tokens:

```
[node:field_pdf]/[file:url]
```

with and without relative path before, and there seems to be a bug that prevents me from saving it when I change the path.

Still can't figure what my path should be..

any help, or advice for the best way to go about it, will be most appreciated.

thanks in advance